# laravel: how to use wherePivot in one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have two one to many pairs:
status > orders
status > tickets

orders

```
id, status_id
1, 5
```

tickets

```
id, status_id
1, 2
```

statuses

```
id, table,    language_id, key, name
 1, 'orders',  1,          1,   'Pending'
 2, 'orders',  1,          2,   'Processing'
 3, 'orders',  1,          3,   'Shipped'
 4, 'orders',  1,          4,   'Canceled'
 5, 'orders',  1,          5,   'Complete'
 6, 'tickets', 1,          1,   'unanswered'
 7, 'tickets', 1,          2,   'answered'
 8, 'tickets', 1,          3,   'closed'
//unique(['table', 'language_id', 'key'])
```

In Order Model

```
public function status()
{
  //ok
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Status', 'status_id', 'key')->where('table', 'orders')->where('language_id', 1);

  //not ok
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Status', 'status_id', 'key')->wherePivot('table', '=', 'orders')->wherePivot('language_id', '=', 1);

}
```

Controller

```
$order = \App\Models\Order::find(1);
dd($order->status);
```

Error message: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`key` = 5 and `pivot` = table and `pivot` = language_id limit 1)

If where() is ok, why there is wherePivot()?
How to use wherePivot correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to querying the result just like that :

```
dd($order->status()->where('language_id', 1));
```

You can also use a custom method in your model.

There is a package dedicated for those stuffs: [Tinker](https://github.com/laravel/tinker)

Comment: I'm still using my statuses table. Your answer is better suitable for me, more simple.  I use this:  $order->status()->where('table', 'orders')->where('language_id', 1)->first()

Comment: I'm glad that I help you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the relationship between Order and Status should be better defined in a different table like ‘order_status’ and relationship between tickets and status be in a table ‘ticket_status’

Then you should rather define the relationship like this:

In the Order Model

```
public function status()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status', 'order_status’, status_id', ‘order_id’)->withPivot('language_id');
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
App\Order::find(1)->status()->wherePivot(‘language_id’, 1)->get();
```

Hope it works.. Typing from my phone

Comment: Thank you for telling me the usage of withPivot() and wherePivot()